# Getting OSM tile server to show English labels in openstreetmap

Tags: label, openstreetmap

I want to build a small map app, but OSM shows the labels in local languages (Russian, Arabic, etc) .I want all the labels to be in English.
 What is mostly advised is to add the "en tag" but I really cannot find any example of how to do this.

My map object in JS is:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [mapCenterLat, mapCenterLon],
  zoom: 3,
  minZoom: 2
  });
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

How should the tag get inserted in the osm url in order to show english labels only?

Comment: You need to use a different tile server with all-english labels. This question has already been answered several times.

Comment: Could you please provide a link? I cannot find any simple map tile server with english labels (free of charge)

Answer (score 2):

See [Map internationalization](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_internationalization) in the OSM wiki for a list of raster and vector tile servers that contain multilingual names.

Also take a look at [Tiles in the OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles), [mapstyle.petschge.de](http://mapstyle.petschge.de/), [Leaflet Provider Demo](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/) and [Map Compare](https://mc.bbbike.org/mc/) for various OSM-based maps. Some of them have all-English place names.

Comment: How does the code look like? I'm using python.

Comment: That depends on the map style you choose. You have to change the tile layer URL.

Comment: How do I add it to this `m = folium.Map(location=placeA, tiles='OpenStreetMap', zoom_start=18)` I took this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uFJ43DvhHg , and I'm new to maps.

Comment: How do I add an URL, I have currently added this URL  **https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}** should the urls look similar to this one?

Comment: Yes, similar to this one and similar to the URL from the original question.

Comment: Where can I copy the URL? For example I went in to this map https://www.osmap.uk/#4/35.70/51.18

Comment: I'm looking for a 100% free and safe English Map URL

Comment: @AnonymousUser In case of Firefox: Tools -> Page Info -> Media. It will show the URL for each tile. However please check the usage policy of this server to see if you are actually allowed to use it for your own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use USGSTopo for English only it works file for me. code in OSMDroid is

```
map.setTileSource(new OnlineTileSourceBase("USGS Topo", 0, 18, 256, "",
            new String[] { "http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/tile/" }) {
        @Override
        public String getTileURLString(long pMapTileIndex) {
            return getBaseUrl()
                    + MapTileIndex.getZoom(pMapTileIndex)
                    + "/" + MapTileIndex.getY(pMapTileIndex)
                    + "/" + MapTileIndex.getX(pMapTileIndex)
                    + mImageFilenameEnding;
        }
    });
```

You can also follow link which provided in Osmdroid [documentation](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/Map-Sources.html). This is only for English not other languages. Please inform any one who had with other languages specially Russian.